# Redux set multiple states at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to update the state Monday, Tuesday....etc based on the appropriate day. Basically I just moved my state to redux store and I have two functions i would like to convert to redux state but I am finding it difficult as it's using `React-hooks` and I am finding it difficult to convert it to redux state. Please can you assist me .

This is my two React functions I am trying to convert to `Redux`:

```
const Restaurant = () => {
  // trying to convert this state to redux store state
  const [Monday, setmonday] =useState([])
  const [Tuesday,settuesday] =useState([])
  const [Wednesday,setwednesday] =useState([])
  const [Thursday, setthursday] =useState([])
  const [Friday, setfriday] =useState([])
  const [Saturday, setsaturday] =useState([])
  const [Sunday, setsunday] =useState([])

  // trying to put this function in my reducer and how it will work with its async alternative
  const getMeals = async (Monday, callback) => {
    try {
      await getMealofDay(Monday, setmonday, 0)
      await getMealofDay(Monday, settuesday, 1)
      await getMealofDay(Monday, setwednesday, 2)
      await getMealofDay(Monday, setthursday, 3)
      await getMealofDay(Monday, setfriday, 4)
      await getMealofDay(Monday, setsaturday, 5)
      await getMealofDay(Monday, setsunday, 6)
    }
    catch{
      console.log("error")
    }
    if (callback) {
      callback()

    }
  }

  const getMealofDay = async (Monday, setDay, i) => {
    try {
      let day = new Date(Monday);
      day.setDate(Monday.getDate() + i);
      let mealId = `${day.getDate()} ${months[day.getMonth() + 1]} ${day.getFullYear()}`
      let meal = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${mealId}`);
      await setDay(JSON.parse(meal))

    } catch{ }

  }
}
```

This is my `Redux` Reducer:

```
import { CREATE_DAY } from '../actions/day'
const initialState = {
    //Days of the week
    Monday: [],
    Tuesday: [],
    Wednesday: [],
    Thursday: [],
    Friday: [],
    Saturday: [],
    Sunday: [],
}
const PlanReducer = (state=initialState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case CREATE_DAY:
            return
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
export default PlanReducer
```

Comment: Redux reducers run synchronously, but redux is capable of [async actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions) using [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (or others). Handle the async logic in the async action creator and dispatch the resultant values to your redux store. If you don't want to try this on your own and see what works or has issues I can take a stab at an implementation.

Comment: Yes please I would really appreciate that thank you

Comment: Sorry it took a bit longer than I was expecting. I don't use redux-thunk, so I wasn't 100% convinced my thoughts would work, so I created a *running* codesandbox to prove to myself it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using async actions

[async actions](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)

Update `getMealofDay` to consume *some* `day` and offset `i` only, and return parsed JSON meal object.

```
const getMealofDay = async (monday, i) => {
  try {
    const day = new Date(monday);
    day.setDate(monday.getDate() + i);

    const mealId = `${day.getDate()} ${months[day.getMonth() + 1]} ${day.getFullYear()}`;
    const meal = await AsyncStorage.getItem(`${mealId}`);

    return JSON.parse(meal);
  } catch {}
};
```

Create a success action type and creator for a specific day

```
export const CREATE_DAY = "CREATE_DAY";
export const mealDaysSuccess = (days) => ({
  type: CREATE_DAY,
  days
});
```

Convert `getMeals` to an async action creator.

The basic pattern you had is this

```
const days = {
  Monday: await getMealofDay(monday, 0),
  Tuesday: await getMealofDay(monday, 1),
  Wednesday: await getMealofDay(monday, 2),
  Thursday: await getMealofDay(monday, 3),
  Friday: await getMealofDay(monday, 4),
  Saturday: await getMealofDay(monday, 5),
  Sunday: await getMealofDay(monday, 6),
}
```

but this isn't very **DRY** and literally waits for each to finish before even starting the next. We can do better. Enqueue all the async functions into an array and `Promise.all` them.

```
export const getMeals = (startDay) => async (dispatch) => {
  const dayPromises = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].map((offset) =>
    getMealofDay(startDay, offset)
  );

  const [
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
  ] = await Promise.all(dayPromises);
  const days = {
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday,
    Sunday
  };

  dispatch(mealDaysSuccess(days));
};
```

In the reducer access the day meals from the action

```
const initialState = {
  //Days of the week
  Monday: [],
  Tuesday: [],
  Wednesday: [],
  Thursday: [],
  Friday: [],
  Saturday: [],
  Sunday: []
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CREATE_DAY:
      return { ...action.days };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[image: Edit redux-set-multiple-states-at-once]

Just follow the setup instructions for adding the redux-thunk middleware to your redux store.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thank you so much for taking the time and explaining the solution step by step. Definitely gave me a better overview on how things are supposed to work. I appreciate it Drew!

Comment: Hello Drew, is it ok to return a relevant value in `getMeals` action so I can re use it in other thunk actions? Say I want to do `const someAction = (startDay,other)=>(dispatch,getState)=>getMeals(startDay)(dispatch,getState).then(meals=>'do something with meals')`

Comment: @HMR I *think* I can follow that code. Thunks *are* able to return values back to the caller, i.e. think form submission to some endpoint with error(s)/success returned back to the UI. Async actions, if they return a promise (I think most would), are also chainable. An async action can also dispatch other async actions.